# I would like to batch re-size images in a terminal

Tags: 14.04, command-line, imagemagick

I've got like 500 images to resize, I'm not going to do that in gimp...a terminal solution would suit me best. On ubuntu 14.04.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802606/how-to-batch-resize-images-in-ubuntu-recursively-within-the-terminal) question on stackoverflow (first posted the question there but someone started naging that stackoverflow is not the best place to ask this question) about batch resizeing using Imagemagic and I guess that is partly what I'm after (I don't care about the recursive part). I need to resize all images so that the longest side of the image will be a set number of pixels. There are images where the longest side will be the width of the image and some where that is the height.

I guess something in the order of:

```
find "*.jpg" | xargs convert -resize ...
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need recursion, you can use Imagemagick's batch tool, `mogrify`. This takes most of the same arguments. To scale the longest size down to 300px, we can offer `-resize "300x300>"`. For safety's sake I've also got this saving the new images into a subdirectory rather than overwriting.

```
# assuming you're in the directory of images
mkdir resized
mogrify -resize "300x300>" -path resized *.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm! But explain to me what does the "300x300>" do. Like I wan't the image to have one side of 300 px, how does the ">" tell mogrify that you want this to only go for the longest side?

Comment: So I guess I found the answer to that question. The ">" means that It will only resize if the image is bigger than the given size. I understand from [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#shrink) page that when giving a size in this fashion 300x300, that this will automatically make imagemagic fit the image in this size. I thought that if I you to do something similar that one side would get scaled up to fit the given size.

Comment: Okay, now it gets slightly more complicated. I need 75px by 75px thumbnails. For that I'd say I need to resize all images so the shortest side is 75 pixels and then cut from that image a 75 by 75 square, preferably from the center...I wouldn't even know where to start...